# Facebook Comment Plugin Post Commets issue

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am trying to integrate facebook comments plug to my application.

I followed steps as it is in the facebook developers website.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments

But when I post the comment I get 
YEXad4AW84s.js:106 POST https://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments/async/createComment/1330513023736568/?dpr=1 500 ()

```
AsyncRequest.send   @   YEXad4AW84s.js:106
la  @   8SngASnhg9O.js:84
fa  @   8SngASnhg9O.js:84
(anonymous) @   8SngASnhg9O.js:84
j.__invokeCallback  @   ZEV_j_MiedY.js:35
j.$Dispatcher_DEPRECATED7   @   ZEV_j_MiedY.js:35
j.dispatch  @   ZEV_j_MiedY.js:35
j.$DevxFluxDispatcher1  @   8SngASnhg9O.js:71
j.handleViewAction  @   8SngASnhg9O.js:71
(anonymous function)    @   8SngASnhg9O.js:72
(anonymous) @   8SngASnhg9O.js:98
ha  @   VkVYtG9EDwz.js:46
h   @   YEXad4AW84s.js:151
hca @   YEXad4AW84s.js:150
hca @   YEXad4AW84s.js:150
y   @   YEXad4AW84s.js:150
z   @   YEXad4AW84s.js:150
hca @   YEXad4AW84s.js:150
hca @   YEXad4AW84s.js:150
ia  @   YEXad4AW84s.js:150
hca @   YEXad4AW84s.js:150
sa  @   YEXad4AW84s.js:150
hca @   YEXad4AW84s.js:150
cm  @   YEXad4AW84s.js:150
yea @   YEXad4AW84s.js:150
vj  @   YEXad4AW84s.js:150
hca @   YEXad4AW84s.js:150
wj  @   YEXad4AW84s.js:150
yj  @   YEXad4AW84s.js:150
hca @   YEXad4AW84s.js:150
ha  @   VkVYtG9EDwz.js:46
x   @   VkVYtG9EDwz.js:238
x   @   VkVYtG9EDwz.js:238
(anonymous) @   VkVYtG9EDwz.js:232
da  @   VkVYtG9EDwz.js:94
z   @   VkVYtG9EDwz.js:94
ia  @   VkVYtG9EDwz.js:94
r   @   VkVYtG9EDwz.js:89
y   @   VkVYtG9EDwz.js:232
ha  @   VkVYtG9EDwz.js:46
ia  @   VkVYtG9EDwz.js:94
r   @   VkVYtG9EDwz.js:89
(anonymous) @   VkVYtG9EDwz.js:93
```